# Theorem that links limits of successions and limits of functions

Tags: calculus, limits

I've a doubt on the theorem that links the limits of functions with the limits of successions.

$$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=l \iff \forall \big\{x_n\big\}_{x\in \mathbb{N}} \mid  x_n\in dom(f) \wedge x\neq c \wedge \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = c$$ holds that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)=l$.

Must the condition $x_n\neq c$ be true $\forall x_n$ or it just means that the considered succession cannot be a constant one? (i.e. $x_n=c$ $ \forall x_n$)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the first one: "The condition must be true for every $x_n$". Of course this excludes in particular constant sequences ($x_n=c$). For example let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0, & x=3 \\ x, & \text{ else} \end{cases}$$ Then if you take the sequence $x_n=3$ for all $n$ "converges" (trivially) to $x_0=3$, so $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(3)=0$$ But 
$$\lim_{x\to 3} f(x)=\lim_{x\to 3}x=3 \neq 0$$ So, the limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $x=3$ exists and is equal to $3$ which is different from $f(3)=0$ but if you take the constant sequence $x_n=3$ you cannot see this.

---

1. The previous example is a constant sequence $x_n=c$ for every $n\in \mathbb N$. But consider also the sequence $$x_n=\begin{cases}3, & n=\text{ even}\\3+\frac1n, & n=\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$ This is a non-constant sequence with $x_n\to 3$ as $n\to \infty$ but exhibits the same problem as above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the clear example! So some of the $x_n$ can be equal to $c$ eventually right? The only condition not allowed is that **all** the $x_n$ are equal to $c$. Because I saw in some books that in the hypotesis it is usually written the condition $x_n \in dom(f)-\big\{c\big\}$ but I wanted to be sure to interpret this in the right way.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! One more question if I may, in your second example, if I consider only the sequence $a_n=3+\frac{1}{n} \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ isn't there the same problem? In that case the sequence would satisfy the hypotesis, so how can that be?

Comment: Moreover, since I'm trying to understand why the condition $x_n\neq c \forall x_n$ must hold, I wonder how can one $x_n=c$ be a problem. Of course as you said, the function could even not be defined in $c$ but in that case, isn't it enough to ask that $x_n \in dom(f)$? I'm a bit confused about it

Comment: Forgive me but I can't see the difference between the two situations in the two examples, in the second one the fact that the limit of $f(x)$ is $3$ while the one of $f(x_n)$ is equal to $f(3)=0$ isn't the same problem of the first example?

Comment: The problem of the first example was that $x_n=3$ for all $n$ yielded $\lim f(x_n)=0$ but the truth is that $\lim f(x)=3$. Problem! The problem in the second example is the same, but know the sequence is not constant. Remember, you asked if the problem occurs only for constant sequences? So, no, not only for constant sequences. So, to sum up:  Let's say: for all $x_n$ except at most for finitely many. Precise enough?